# Make webpack include a global jquery plugin in the bundle

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, kendo-ui

I'm working with an older ui library that requires their ui components be extensions of jQuery. We have some files that extend their ui components. These files need to be run in the global context before the main logic of the app starts up.

Here's the index.js file:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import '@progress/kendo-ui';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    $('#main').kendoTelephone();
    window.jquery = $;
});
```

here's the file that makes the kendoTelephone extension:

```
import '@progress/kendo-ui';

const Telephone = kendo.ui.MaskedTextBox.extend( {
    init: function(element, options) {
        options || (options = {});
        options.mask = "(000) 000-0000";
        kendo.ui.MaskedTextBox.fn.init.call(this, element, options);
    },
    options: Object.assign( {},  kendo.ui.MaskedTextBox.prototype.options, {
        name: 'Telephone'
    } ),
});

kendo.ui.plugin(Telephone);

export default Telephone;
```

How do I make it so that webpack will:
1. Include the telephone extension file in the bundle
2. and bundle it in such a way that it runs in the global context

Here's my webpack config:

```
{
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js',
    },
    mode: 'development',
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: require.resolve('./src/telephone.js'),
            use: ['script-loader']
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new wp.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery"
        }),
    ]
}
```